# MvcSiteMapProvider with custom routes

Tags: mvcsitemapprovider

I have a web app that has a virtual web app within it in IIS. The site map exists in the parent web app and want to have certain nodes route to the virtual app views.

I tried to define custom routes in the parent web global.asax but the provider seems to append the route to every node by default even if the node has no route configured. What's the appropriate way to use custom routes, or route to my scenario with MvcSiteMapProvider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you take a look at this :

https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Dynamic-sitemaps

When creating the dynamic nodes can specify the Action and Controllers - see if that works for the two different links..